# Trying to compute e^x when x_0 = 1

Tags: c++, math, taylor-series

I am trying to compute the Taylor series expansion for e^x at x_0 = 1. I am having a very hard time understanding what it really is I am looking for. I am pretty sure I am trying to find a decimal approximation for when e^x when x_0 = 1 is. However, when I run this code when x_0 is = 0, I get the wrong output. Which leads me to believe that I am computing this incorrectly.

Here is my class e.hpp

```
#ifndef E_HPP
#define E_HPP

class E
{
    public:
        int factorial(int n);
        double computeE();

    private:
        int fact = 1;
        int x_0 = 1;
        int x = 1;
        int N = 10;
        double e = 2.718;
        double sum = 0.0;

};
```

Here is my e.cpp

```
#include "e.hpp"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int E::factorial(int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        fact = fact * i;
    }

    return fact;
}

double E::computeE()
{
    sum = std::pow(e,x_0);

    for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
    {
        sum += ((std::pow(x-x_0,i))/factorial(i));
    }
    return e * sum;
}
```

In main.cpp

```
#include "e.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    E a;
    std::cout << "E calculated at x_0 = 1: " << a.computeE() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "E Calculated with std::exp: " << std::exp(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Output: 
`E calculated at x_0 = 1: 7.38752`
`E calculated with std::exp: 2.71828`

When I change to x_0 = 0.
`E calculated at x_0 = 0: 7.03102` 
`E calculated with std::exp: 2.71828`

What am I doing wrong? Am I implementing the Taylor Series incorrectly? Is my logic incorrect somewhere?

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain their reasoning?

Comment: Your factorial function is vulnerable to overflow. And don't compute it in the first place: compute a running divisor instead. Much more computationally stable, and faster.

Comment: In addition, why are you using hardcoded value of `e`, and raising it by power with `std::pow`, instead of using [`std::exp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp)?

Comment: @Bathsheba, can you give me an example of a running divisor?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I am trying to approximate e^x when x_0 is equal to 1. I need to know e before hand since the Taylor Series expansion for when x_0 is equal to 1 is: e^x_0 * the sum of n=0 to inf (x-x_0)^n/n!. I raise it so I already have the first term.

Comment: @Sailanarmo What? Re-read the comment. You didn't understand it. Why are you using `std::pow(e,x_0);` instead of `std::exp(x_0);`? And `std::exp(1)` instead of the `e` in `return e * sum;`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I am perhaps using this incorrectly. I am using `std::pow(e,x_0)` because that is the first term I need to have in the Taylor Series when x_0 is equal to 1. I then have to multiply that by the summation of the series of (x-x_0)^n/n!. I simply hardcoded e in there instead of using `std::exp(1)` because I did not think about it. But that is something that can be changed.

Comment: @sailanarmo you do realize that `pow(x, y)` is computed as `exp(x*log(y))`? (So if you use `pow` you are in fact "doubly cheating").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, your logic is incorrect somewhere.

Like Dan says, you have to reset `fact` to 1 each time you calculate the factorial.  You might even make it local to the `factorial` function.

In the return statement of `computeE` you are multiplying the sum by `e`, which you do not need to do.  The sum is already the taylor approximation of e^x.

The taylor series for e^x about `0` is sum _i=0 ^i=infinity (x^i / i!), so `x_0` should indeed be 0 in your program.

Technically your `computeE` computes the right value for `sum` when you have x_0=0, but it's kind of strange.  The taylor series starts at `i=0`, but you start the loop with `i=1`.  However, the first term of the taylor series is `x^0 / 0! = 1` and you initialize `sum` to `std::pow(e, x_0) = std::pow(e, 0) = 1` so it works out mathematically.

(Your `computeE` function *also* computed the right value for `sum` when you had `x_0 = 1`.  You initialized `sum` to std::pow(e, 1) = e, and then the for loop didn't change its value at all because x - x_0 = 0.)

However, as I said, in either case you don't need to multiply it by `e` in the return statement.

I would change the `computeE` code to this:

```
double E::computeE()
{
    sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        sum += ((std::pow(x-x_0,i))/factorial(i));
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

and set `x_0 = 0`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess the reason I am starting it this way is because I want to compute e^x when x_0 = 1 instead of x_0 = 0. Which changes the Taylor Series from the sum of n=0 to infinity x^n/n! to e multiplied by the sum of n=0 to infinity (x-1)^n/n! I could not think of any other way to do this. And apologies for the formatting on this. I am not sure if SO supports math notation.

Comment: If you're trying to compute e using the taylor series about 1, then as you said each term is multiplied by e, so you need to _already know_ the value of e.

Comment: Okay, so this is where I seem to be struggling. Should I not be removing `e` then? When I remove `e` I get the output `2.71799` which I believe all I am trying to do is just approximate e^x. When I set x_0 = 0, I get the output 2.71828 as expected. Is this still wrong then?

Comment: @jcarpenter `e^x0` to be precise, since it is parameterized

Answer (score 3):

"fact" must be reset to 1 each time you calculate factorial. It should be a local variable instead of a class variable.

When "fact" is a class varable, and you let "factorial" change it to, say 6, that means that it will have the vaule 6 when you call "factorial" a second time. And this will only get worse. Remove your declaration of "fact" and use this instead:

```
int E::factorial(int n)
{
    int fact = 1;
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        fact = fact * i;
    }

    return fact;
}
```

Comment: I have changed it so `fact` is at the top of `int E::factorial(int n)` I still receive the same output of 7.38752. So can you explain to me why that change was needed when it didn't seem to make a difference with the output? I hope that question did not come off badly.

Comment: Move `int fact = 1;` inside factorial function body. Otherwise you are using previous `fact` value as starting value for next function call

Comment: @MBo, I have moved it over officially. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Write less code.

Don't use factorial.

Here it is in Java.  You should have no trouble converting this to C++:

```
/**
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148579/trying-to-compute-ex-when-x-0-1
 * @link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series
 */
public class TaylorSeries {

    private static final int DEFAULT_NUM_TERMS = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int xmax = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.valueOf(args[0]) : 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < xmax; ++i) {
            System.out.println(String.format("x: %10.5f series exp(x): %10.5f function exp(x): %10.5f", (double)i, exp(i), Math.exp(i)));
        }
    }

    public static double exp(double x) {
        return exp(DEFAULT_NUM_TERMS, x);
    }

    // This is the Taylor series for exp that you want to port to C++
    public static double exp(int n, double x) {
        double value = 1.0;
        double term = 1.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            term *= x/i;
            value += term;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```